# Why does url.action sometimes render links differently in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've noticed that sometime when I use url.action that the link rendered is different, but I'm not sure why. As an example sometimes I get

```
/someapp/report/save?projectNumber=61033651
```

but other times I get

```
/someapp/report/61033651/save
```

The code I''m using where I get the first url is

```
formaction="@Url.Action("Save", "report", new { projectNumber = Model.ProjectNumber })
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

My route attribute for this action is

```
[Route("Project/{projectNumber}/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/save")]
```

Here's my default route

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Result of `Url.Action` depends on defined routes. Does this happen, when you specify route name using `Url.Action`?

Comment: @PawełHemperek Yes it does.  I have updated my question with the route attribute

Comment: Do you have any routes defined in `Global.asax`?

Comment: @PawełHemperek I just have the default route.  updated the question

Comment: Have you enabled attribute rotes through `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` ? Take a loot at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/ . Regards.

Comment: Just for clarification - when you're saying _sometimes_ you one time when you enter the page you get one version and some other time the other? Or do you mean, that you call `@Url.Action` in different places and you get different, but non changing results?